# Why do I see packets that their source or destination IPs are not my IP address while I'm using my VPN?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I'm new to the networking world and I'm using Wireshark to learn stuffs about the network.

I was hanging around in Wireshark while I was using my VPN for circumventing the internet filter (living in a dictatorship country).

While I was using the VPN I see packets that their source or destination IP was neither my IP nor VPN server IP.

I considered two things about my problem:

1- I know my VPN uses its VPN server to send my whole packets to that server then forward them to my deserved destination, then take the response and send it to my client (is that correct?).

2- In Wireshark, I just can see the packets that their either source or destination address is my IP address.

My packets before using VPN:
[image]

As you can see, their either source or destination IP is my IP (192.168.1.101).

After using VPN, VPN:

[image]

Wireshark:

[image]

I tried filtering packets with my IP like this `ip.addr == 192.168.1.101` to see only the packets that their either source or destination IP was my private IP, and guess what? nothing was changed. Why did this happen? Wasn't that supposed to filter my packets?

I also checked those packets' MAC and compared them with my MAC, and they were identical.

So my main question is why these kinds of wandering packets were showed by Wireshark? Is my VPN client insecure and trying to sending my data to other places? Or I'm wrong about how my VPN works?

Also, I appreciate it If somebody tells me more explanation about how my VPN or Wireshark works so that I have these types of packets in my Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your considerations, point no.1 is right, that's how a typical VPN works and point no.2 is wrong.

Wireshark can capture any packet (any source IP or destination IP) flowing in and out of a network adapter technically known as NIC card. NIC cards are the way through which you can connect to a network (Internet). A quick brief of NIC [over here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-network-interface-card-nic)

A typical VPN client software would form a virtual NIC to encrypt and send your traffic through it. A quick brief of VPNs [over here](https://www.namecheap.com/vpn/how-does-vpn-virtual-private-network-work/)

So, to see the required traffic in Wireshark, you must capture traffic from an appropriate interface (NIC card). The answer [over here](https://superuser.com/questions/882007/how-to-record-traffic-which-is-inside-a-vpn) might be helpful.